# Move up navigation icon in toolbar to the right

Tags: android, android-toolbar, up-navigation

I've implemented up navigation to my Navigationdrawer activity.

```
private void setupActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

But it doesnt sho up, I guess it's covered by the icon for opening the navigation drawer.

**Question:**

How can I position the up navigation icon either next to the drawer activity or on the right of the toolbar?icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code: to add your `custom` Back arrow icon in `actionbar` Right side...

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(actionBar.getDisplayOptions()
        | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(actionBar.getThemedContext());
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_back_icon);
ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
        ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.RIGHT
                | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
layoutParams.rightMargin = 50;
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
actionBar.setCustomView(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not display a **UP Button** and a **Navigation Drawer Icon** in Android at the same time. That is also the reason it is not possible for you to achieve this so easylie.

A few years ago Google released the Material Design Guidlines with Material Design to achieve that developers develop apps that feel the same and behave the same like all other. The user should always know how to navigate through your app.

I don't know how you designed your Application but you should only use the **UP Button** if you want to navigate from a opend Activity to the previous Activity.

I recommend to read the [Navigation Guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation.html) from Google to better understand what I mean.

I hope, that i helped you.

Comment: Yes, thank you for you answer, you saved me from researching on this topic :D but however my problem still remains. Maybe you can help me with it if i give further information. The activity named above is not the mainactivity, and the reason I'm using the navigation drawer is that I'm using a fragment manager, the fragments can be accessed through the navigation drawer. Is there another way to access the different fragments?

Comment: @Quacksilber I don't understand your question. You would like to implement in your Activity a Navigation Drawer in which you always switch between Fragments. Is it right?

Comment: I allready have a navigation drawer activity to select different fragments. I nees a way to switch between these fragments and to get back to my mainactivity, and if I understood you right, thats not possible with a navigation drawers bc of the google design guidelines?

Comment: @Quacksilber So you have an **Activity A** which opens an **Activity B** and in the **Activity B** there is a Navigation drawer and you would like to have a UP Button where you can go from B to A. Did I understand you correctly?